# Modify(prefixing or postfixing) existing regular expression to exclude trailing period from matches

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to write javascript regular expression from find all URLs from a text frame.  However, I want not to include trailing dot(which is generally end of paragraph/sentence).

For example, in following line, it should match only http://example1.com  and http://example2.com (want to  trailing period not part of match match)

> For more info check http://example1.com. Another link is http://example2.com.

I have already have regular expression (R) but problem is that it include trailing dot. Now, How can I modify such that it excludes trailing dot from all matching expressions. I tried with negative look ahead:

```
(?!.*\.)(R)
```

but it excludes everything as period anywhere in URL, prevent matching.

In summary:

I want to modify regular expression to exclude ending period from matches. I do not want to break format of existing regular expression. I want modified regular expression by just prefixing or post-fixing existing regular expression.

Note: existing regular expression will also match expression without trailing period. So, just excluding all matches ending with period will be sufficient.

Comment: escape the `.` in the regex?!?

Comment: what's your current regex?

Comment: Add `\b` at the end. Or, if you need to literally avoid matches with `.` at the end, add `\b(?!\.)` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix this by negative look behind.(requires latest version of javascript):

change

```
R
```

to

```
(R)(?<!\.)
```